# How to add a view in a Tablerow in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I want to add a vertical line view within an tableRow (between two textview)and mylayout is like this.
I dont want full border to that Table Layout.

```
<TableRow android:background="@color/alto">

 <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="@string/minimum_fare"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minimum_fare_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</TableRow>
```

Layout should look like 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a line you can either use an image of a line or you can use an empty view with background set to a specific color and of specific width; something like this:

```
<TableRow android:background="@color/alto">

 <TextView
        ------------
        ------------/>
//This will create a 1dp thick line with black background.
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp" //
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#555" />

  <TextView
        ------------
        ------------/>
</TableRow>
```